# Attacks on the RawCBC-MAC if the final step of encrypting with a second key isn't done

Tags: mac, chosen-plaintext-attack, cbc-mac

This is from Boneh's lecture ECBC-MAC

[image]

Here is also a link to the lecture itself - https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto/lecture/QYT6i/cbc-mac-and-nmac

CBC-MAC with $(K_1, K_2)$ on a message $M$ applies RawCBCMAC with $K_1$ to message $M$ & takes the output tag & runs the PRF on the tag using a second key $K_2$

Boneh explains a chosen message attack on RawCBCMAC

- Ask the oracle for the tag on a 1 block message $m$. Let's say the tag is $t$.
- Now the same tag $t$ will also be the tag for a 2nd message $ (m || t \oplus m)$

Yes, this will indeed work.

I can think of another attack on the RawCBCMAC

- Ask the oracle for the tag on a message $m$ (can be any number of blocks). Let's say the tag is $t$.
- Ask the oracle for the tag on a single block message ($w \oplus t$). Let's say the tag is $t'$
- Now the tag for the message $(m || w)$ is same as $t'$

Is this also a valid attack on RawCBC or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this also a valid attack on RawCBC [...]?

Yes. Writing down the expressions, we get $t=F(k,m)$ and $t'=F(k,w\oplus t)$ - while abusing notation and meaning RawCBCMAC for multi-block invocations of $F$. Now the actual tag for $(m\|w)$ would be $t''=F(k,F(k,m)\oplus w)=F(k,t\oplus w)$ which is equal to $t'$.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. I really apologize for it. I have updated it now. t' is the tag of (w XOR t) & not of just w. I again apologize for the mistake

Comment: @user93353 Yes, the new variant works.